# Cakephp redirect after x seconds?

Tags: cakephp, redirect, wait

I am looking for a simple redirect for cakephp 2.1 with a wait time.

I'd like the view page to redirect after -lets say 5 seconds- to an external url.

Any idea how I could implement this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest solutions either involve jquery/javascrpt, meta or php headers in a view. I do not believe cake has a dedicate way to do this but an alternative could be a simple for loop and just do a simple +1 count to like 5000 or whatever value is needed to take 5 seconds and then do the normal cake redirect.

simple view examples.

php header

```
header('Refresh: 5; URL=http://site.com/controller/action');
```

meta

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;url=http://site.com/controller/action"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer maybe late. But it is useful for the other who want to use CakePHP View Helper:

```php
    echo $this->Html->meta(
        null,
        null,
        ['http-equiv' => 'refresh', 'content' => '10;url=https://example.com/controller/action']
    );
```

It works with CakePHP 2.x, 3.x and 4.x